# Maximal region where Dulac's criterion applies

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=y \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=-\mu(x^2-1)y-x=0
\end{cases}$$

What is the maximal region to which Dulac's criterion with $g(x)=1$ applies?

**My attempt:**
Using Dulac's criterion with $g(x)=1$ gives us

$\nabla\cdot (g\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt})=-\mu(x^2-1).$
I'm stuck here. Dulac's criterion says that if the above expression has one sign throughout a simply connected set $R$ then, there are no closed orbits lying entirely in $R$. But how to get the maximal region where it applies?

Comment: For $|x| < 1$ we have that $-\mu(x^2-1)$ has the same sign.

Comment: @Cesareo, but don't we have that $-\mu(x^2-1)$ for $|x|>1$ as well?

Comment: Is this region simply connected?

Comment: @Cesareo, oh, right, it's not simply connected, because there is a hole in it, thanks